# Request mapkit annotations to the server by position and zoom level

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I have this question:

I have an API server to request points nearest a position (lat & long) and distance (km)

I would to call this API when the user make a pan on the map..so I would to calculate the distance parameter in function of zoom level..

How can I obtain this?

At this moment I have this MapKit delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = mapView.bounds.size.width / mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
NSLog(@"currentZoom:%f", currentZoomScale);
    [self.dataReader sendServerRequestWithCoordinate:mapView.region.center andDistance:[self getDistanceByZoomLevel:currentZoomScale];

}

- (float) getDistanceByZoomLevel:(MKZoomScale) zoomLevel {
 /// ?????? ////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate the distance based on a "zoom level" or "zoom scale".

Map Kit and Core Location have methods and functions to calculate distance given coordinates or map points.

Assume you want to use the diagonal distance (from top-left to bottom-right) covered by the currently visible map.

The corner coordinates (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`s) can be obtained from the map view's `region` property and then you can use the `distanceFromLocation` method to calculate the distance between the two coordinates.

The corner map points (`MKMapPoint`s) can be obtained from the map view's `visibleMapRect` property and then you can use the `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints` function to get the distance between them.

Here's an example using the map points:

```
MKMapRect vmr = mapView.visibleMapRect;

//vmr.origin is the top-left corner MKMapPoint

MKMapPoint bottomRightMapPoint = 
    MKMapPointMake(vmr.origin.x + vmr.size.width, 
                   vmr.origin.y + vmr.size.height);

CLLocationDistance distanceMeters = 
    MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(vmr.origin, bottomRightMapPoint);
```

Of course, if you want kilometers instead of meters, divide `distanceMeters` by 1000.0.

Also, if by "distance" you actually want the *radius* (distance from the center point), then also divide `distanceMeters` by 2.0.